# css { content: "text"}, how do I add tags?

Tags: css

I wrote some dummy css. Instead of a tag I got escaped characters. How can I add a div tag instead?

```
.HeaderName:after{
content: "<div class=\"Name2\">text</div>";
}

.Name2 {
color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 45):

The `content` declaration cannot add tags to the page (tags are structural); additionally, CSS is meant for presentation changes, not structural content changes.

Consider using jQuery, instead, such as:

```
$(".HeaderName").after("your html here");
```

Comment: Lastly, text added via the CSS content property is not inserted into the DOM, so it can't be acted on later by Javascript, etc.  I agree that it should not be used in general, and certainly should not be used for this purpose. +1

Comment: In certain contexts, the use of the content property could be stylistically correct. For instance, adding a comma after certain pieces of content:

<span class="city">New York</span><span class="state">NY</span>

.city:after { content: ", "; }

So, it's not _always_ wrong, but it's not by any means recommended.

Comment: One useful example is putting colon (:) after labels or asterisk (*) after required fields. It can be agreed that these are just presentation details and a screen read should not read 'colon' or 'star' as part of the content.

Comment: There are more useful examples. Especially considering icon fonts!

Answer (score 14):

If you need that extra tag only to make the added text red, just do this:

```
.HeaderName:after{
    content: "text";
    color:red;
}
```

Tested on Chrome.

Answer (score 12):

You can't insert tags using `content:` in CSS. Here is the relevant part of the spec; see [the 'content' property](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/CR-CSS2-20090908/generate.html#propdef-content) in the CSS 2.1 spec.