# Append horizontal rule to each <li>

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

For my `<ul>` list, I would like to add a `<hr>` after each element of a list. The Result should render like:

```
<ul class="mylist">
    <li>
        moooo!
        <hr width="40%">
    </li>
    <li>
        maaaaa!
        <hr width="40%">
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

It is bad style adding `<hr>` to each `<li>` so I would like to refractor this using css only. I cannot use:

```
.mylist > li: after{
    content: "<hr>"
}
```

as content would escape the characters.

I also do **not** want to use jQuery:

```
$('.mylist').find('li').append('<hr width="40%">');
```

So the question is, how could I append `<hr width="40%">` to *each* `<li>` of a certain list using **css3** ?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

*jQuery Solution*

Just realized that you wanted to nest the `hr` element inside the `li` before you close it, yes it's perfectly valid, so simply use `append()`, and note, you *cannot do this* using CSS only, as you cannot modify DOM using CSS, you need to use jQuery or JS

```
jQuery("ul li").append("<hr />");
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pyN3j/1/)

---

*CSS Solution*

If you don't need an extra element, or you don't want a jQuery solution(As you want)

Using `hr` element as a direct child to `ul` element is not a valid markup, instead, you can use a `border-bottom` for each `li` which will behave same as `hr` does, still if you want an explicit way to do so, say for controlling the `width` of the separator without changing the `width` of `li` than you can do it like this

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pyN3j/)

```
ul li:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    width: 40%;
    margin: 10px;
    background: #f00;
}
```

Here, am just creating a virtual `block` level element, which doesn't actually exists in the DOM, but it will just do the thing which you need. You can just design the element, the same way you style a normal `div`. You can also use `border` on this but to keep the thin line horizontally centered, I've assigned `height: 1px;` and than am using `margin` to space up.

Answer (score 21):

I think it's better to use CSS for this. for example you can stop using `<hr>` tag, instead do something like:

```
<ul class="mylist">
    <li>
        moooo!
    </li>
    <li>
        maaaaa!
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

and then with CSS:

```
.mylist li { border-bottom: 1px solid black; }
```

There are other options too, for example if you want to show the horizontal line only for some list items, you can give them a class and add a CSS rule only for that class. like this:

```
<ul class="mylist">
    <li class="hr">
        moooo!
    </li>
    <li>
        maaaaa!
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

and CSS:

```
.mylist li.hr { border-bottom: 1px solid black; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this:

```
<ul>
   <li></li>
</ul>
<hr/>
```

Thats simple. If you have nested `ul` and `li` then you use `li` instead of `<hr/>` or simply `<hr/>` inside a `<li></li>` tag. See below. Its purely your choice.

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <ul><li></li></ul>
  </li>
  <li style="height:1px;border:solid 1px #666"> </li> // or you can also use 
  <li><hr/></li>
  <li> 
    <ul>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Nesting the horizontal rule within its own list item negates the purpose of using a list, as these are not list items. Imagine how that would playback to a screenreader, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Tags in content are not allowed and even if it would be very misleading ([css { content: "text"}, How do i add tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102259/css-content-text-how-do-i-add-tags))

If you think is wrong to add `<hr>` in HTML than it is wrong adding with css (if it would be possible) or js. IMHO a first You should try to use border of `<li`> if result won't be as expected add that `<hr>`

Answer (score 0):

Insert A `Class` That Creates A `bottom-border:` For Each `<li>`

```
<!--########## STYLE EACH li USING CLASS ##########-->
<style>
  .hr {
     width:40%;
     border-bottom:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.7);
   }

</style>

<!--########### PAGE CONTENT ############-->
<ul class="mylist">
<li class="hr">
    -CONTENT-

</li>
<li class="hr">
    -CONTENT-
</li>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS:

```css
li:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
}
```