# Horizontal Rules to replace with border

Tags: jquery, css, border, rules

I have options menu and i want to use Horizontal Rules on each options instead of using bottom of border, it possible to put bottom border into the Transparent and replace with Horizontal Rules in css or jquery! if so how to that write that code!

Comment: Can you show us what you've already tried?

Comment: a fiddle of ur code would be usefull..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i my guess is correct

```
.after()
```

can solve your problem.

[check if this is what you want](http://jsfiddle.net/mayekarsaurabh/pyN3j/5/)

Comment: I am looking for a similar solution but this solution do not work cross browser, to me only on chrome. any idea how to work on firefox also IE?

Comment: @user3023823 which one do you want out of that 2 cause the adding new option in a disabled state is working everywhere for me..

Answer (score 0):

**[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19197567/add-horizontal-rule-after-each-li)** is a link to the solution you might be looking for.

Comment: I use (select options) not (ul or li), i tried that code with select options is not working. Does is work under select options!

Answer (score 0):

You mean on a `<select>` element? Then you certainly cannot, read the spec: [www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.6](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.6).

A `<select>` element should only contain a `<optgroup>` or `<option>` elements and there should be at least one.

So any other element inside the `<select>` the browser will drop it or will not render it on the menu.

Can you at least explain why border-bottom is not good enough for you.