# I want add a html element after one html element in jquery ? is it possible in Css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a tab design. that active tab identified by a down arrow. i want to create that arrow when i mouse hover only. i don't want place that arrow to all tabs. please reffer the below image. is it possible in css ( may be in after or before pseudo class ) or jquery.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: If you can put your code in a jsFiddle, it would be helpful.

Comment: You can just use :hover:after and :hover:before to create the arrow when hovered. The arrow can be created with a image or with the border trick.

Comment: Border trick? could you explain please?

Comment: Here is a explanation: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

Comment: Why not have span on all sections and make them visible on hover?

Comment: Check my answer for an example of the "border-trick"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how you could use the [border-trick](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/):

```
#menu
{
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    border:1px solid #d0d0d0;
    /*gradient generator ftw*/
    background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(249,249,249) 45%, rgb(255,255,255) 72%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(249,249,249) 45%, rgb(255,255,255) 72%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(249,249,249) 45%, rgb(255,255,255) 72%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(249,249,249) 45%, rgb(255,255,255) 72%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(249,249,249) 45%, rgb(255,255,255) 72%);

    background-image: -webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        left bottom,
        left top,
        color-stop(0.45, rgb(249,249,249)),
        color-stop(0.72, rgb(255,255,255))
    );
}


#menu a
{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 300%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #848484;
}

#menu a:hover
{
    color: black;
}

#menu a:hover:before
{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -1px; 
  left: 40%;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid white;
  z-index: 1;
}

#menu a:hover:after
{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -1px; 
  left: 40%;
  border-left: 11px solid transparent;
  border-right: 11px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 11px solid #d0d0d0;
}
```

The `:after` pseudo-class is the border of the arrow where the `:before` pseudo-class is the arrow itself.

As you can see the `:after` pseudo-class is just an other arrow that is beneath the `:before` pseudo-class. With the width 1px bigger, you can see it sticking out that will function as a border.

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rfn3j/)**

Answer (score 1):

shape can added using [**`:after and :before`**](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/11/22/css-quick-tip-css-arrows-and-shapes-without-markup/) pseudo elements.

Comment: by this property can add some plain text only. but i want add a <span> tag.

Comment: @Arul [it is not possible to use html tags inside the `content`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102259/css-content-text-how-do-i-add-tags).  Incase if you want then you have to do either using jQuery or JS

Comment: @arul; @user1671639 is right, you can use `:before` and `:after` and style them with to look like arrows. See the comments and link above by @nkmol

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'm not sure about the capabilities of CSS, but it's definitely possible using JQuery `.hover()`

JS

```
$( "li.menu_item" ).hover(
 function() {
  $( this ).append( $( "<span class='arrow'></span>" ) );
 }, function() {
  $( this ).find( "span:last" ).remove();
 }
);
```

Look at http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell with css you can not append a new html element. You can write styles for a particuar tag,id or class.

You can already code an html structure with in the page(make it ,css-> display:none). on css events like :hover you can display:block it.

But in Jquery you can do it by the following methods.

[Jquery before](http://api.jquery.com/before/)

[Jquery After](http://api.jquery.com/after/)

or search for the .append() method